# Adding drop shadow to UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, shadow

I've a plain UITableView (not grouped) that I want to add a dropshadow to left and to the right.

[image]

How can I achieve this? I've tried:

```
[self.tableView.layer setShadowColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
[self.tableView.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 0)];
[self.tableView.layer setShadowRadius:5.0];
[self.tableView.layer setShadowOpacity:1];
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you made sure that `clipToBounds` and `maskToBounds` are set to `NO` (for the view and layer respectively)?

Comment: Thanks guy, you're right! If you add an answer I'll mark it as correct answer.

Comment: [**TableView rounded corners and Shadow Swift**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33793211/tableview-rounded-corners-and-shadow-swift/36399505#36399505)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You need to make sure `clipsToBounds` and `masksToBounds` are set to `NO` on the view and layer respectively.

```
self.tableView.clipsToBounds = NO;
self.tableView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. But if I set tableView.layer.masksToBounds = NO; & tableView.clipsToBounds = NO; , my tableviewcell moves above tableviews bounds. I have tableview , imageview in my viewController. So some part is used by table view & some part is used by iamgeview. Can you help me with it ?

Comment: @iOSAppDev Please take a look at my answer. It will prevent the problem you are running into.

Comment: You d'better put an UIView behind the UITableView and add the shadow to the UIView.

Comment: I am facing a strange issue when I set the cliptoBounds and masktoBounds to false for my dynamic sized UItableVIew. Here is a recoded video for the same https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_BGThAIbJgY8blxLLFDKD8_H76Vdx7Q5/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 6):

I would like to share my solution: 
This requires you to subclass UITableView and add a property, for the sake of demonstration let's call it showShadow. Add this to your table view's .h file:

`@property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL showShadow;`

and its corresponding @synthesize in the .m file to create getter and setter methods:

`@synthesize showShadow;`

Then add an iVar `UIView *shadowView;` to the table view's .h file.
Now in the `- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame` method of your subclassed UITableView add the following piece of code to set up the view that will eventually cast the shadow:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        shadowView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.frame];
        shadowView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        shadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.1;
        shadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(3, 3);
        shadowView.layer.shadowRadius = 1;



    }
    return self;
}
```

And, finally, write the setter method to show/hide the shadow:

```
-(void)setShowShadow:(BOOL)s{

    showShadow = s;

    if(s){
        [self.superview insertSubview:shadowView belowSubview:self];
    }else{
        [shadowView removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Additionally if you would like to move the table (for whatever reason), you should override the `-setFrame:` method to also move the shadowView along with it (as it is not in the table view's view hierarchy):

```
-(void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame{

     [super setFrame:frame];
     shadowView.frame = frame;

}
```

You have successfully enabled shadows ! Use it like this :

```
MySubclassedTableView *table = [[MySubclassedTableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 200, 280, 200)];
        [self.view addSubview:table];
        table.showShadow = YES;
```

**WARNING:**

> You have to set the showShadow property **AFTER** you add your table view, because the line table.showShadow will call the line [self.superview insertSubview:shadowView belowSubview:self]; which requires the table view to be existent.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the white glow I am seeing the shadow? You have no offset set, so it is doing exactly what you want. For a shadow, set the color to black, and give it an offset of maybe 3,5 or something.

Comment: No, that image is what I've tried to achieve. Now I've fixed with mattjgalloway comment. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Adding Swift version of solution (which helped me a lot) provided by @mattjgalloway

```
your_TableView.clipsToBounds = false
your_TableView..layer.masksToBounds = false
your_TableView..layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
your_TableView..layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
your_TableView..layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
your_TableView..layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
```