# UITableView with drop shadow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I know how to add a shadow around `UIViews` and even to animate them when the views `bounds` change. However I've come across a view that is a little more tricky it seems. `UITableView`

Adding a shadow around this view is easy enough and even going by this example: [Adding drop shadow to UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012071/adding-drop-shadow-to-uitableview)
It works well. However my problem is that I need the shadow to go around the last `cell` in the `UITableView` and not it's `bounds`. So, top, sides and bottom would be the last cell in the `UITableView`.

Thinking about how it'd work leaves me to believe there is a better solution. Maybe if I was able to adjust the `UitableView`s frame based on the number of cells? However the cells are dynamic and I don't know their heights until runtime.

Any suggestions would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

something like...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  if (indexPath.row == [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section] - 1) {
    // last row
    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
    cell.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:cell.bounds].CGPath;
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only one option for your requirement :

1) Add shadow for `top, left and right` of `UITableView`.

2) Add shadow to `bottom` of `last UITableViewCell`. For this you might need to increase height of last cell of UITableView;