# TableView rounded corners and shadow

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, storyboard, tableview

I have a tableview with three rows. I am trying to make the table rows have rounded corners and also a shadow effect around the entire tableview. For some reason, I cannot make the tableview both have the rounded corners and shadow effect but I could do them separately if I comment out the code responsible for one of the features. Here is the code I am using:

```
//this is for shadow effect

tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

tableView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor   

tableView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2.0, height: 2.0

tableView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0

tableView.layer.shadowRadius = 2

// This is for rounded corners

tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10

tableView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIView with shadow, rounded corners and custom drawRect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591389/uiview-with-shadow-rounded-corners-and-custom-drawrect)

Comment: That doesn't work quite well since I am using a table view.

Comment: It should work, you're still editing the view layer.

Comment: I am a bit confused as to how I could use my tableview instance. Could I make an IBOutlet for my table view and somehow use that in the answer from the link you provided?

Comment: Are you using `UITableViewController` or `UITableView` ?

Comment: I am using a UITableView inside a view controller.

Comment: Then Yes, just drag and drop it and create an `IBOutlet`

Comment: What would I replace in the link you provided with my uitableview? Would it be the superview variable or something else that I can't seem to figure out?

Comment: Yes, instead of `UIView`, you use `UITableView`, All you need to do is create an `IBOutlet` by drag and dropping it into your class file and in your `viewDidLoad:` method just do the same as the link i send you.

Comment: I can't seem to get it still. Tried to change superview and shadow view to equal tableview but doesn't work. Here is what I currently have: https://pastee.org/8dh33

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can add your table view to a container view and add drop shadow to that container view:

```
let containerView:UIView = UIView(frame:CGRect(x: 10, y: 100, width: 300, height: 400))
self.tableView = UITableView(frame: containerView.bounds), style: .Plain)
containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
containerView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor   
containerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2.0, height: 2.0)
containerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
containerView.layer.shadowRadius = 2
// This is for rounded corners
self.tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
self.tableView.layer.masksToBounds = true
self.view.addSubview(containerView)
containerView.addSubview(self.tableView)
```

### Edit

Swift 3.0:

```
let containerView:UIView = UIView(frame:CGRect(x: 10, y: 100, width: 300, height: 400))
self.tableView = UITableView(frame: containerView.bounds, style: .plain)
containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
containerView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
containerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2.0, height: 2.0)
containerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
containerView.layer.shadowRadius = 2
    
self.tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
self.tableView.layer.masksToBounds = true
self.view.addSubview(containerView)
containerView.addSubview(self.tableView)
```

[image]

Comment: containerView:UIView = UIView(frame:self.tableView.frame) is giving me an issue.. Don't seem to know what it is. If I change the first line to: "let containerView = UIView(frame:self.tableView.frame)", it force closes.

Comment: Be warned that this code will make the delete functionality stop working.

Comment: @JohnDoe You're going to have to be more specific. I just ran this code and deleting worked fine. See the gif I attached to my answer.

Comment: That is odd.  Yesterday I could swipe but not tap the delete button. But now the swipe would not work at all on my actual project.  Just now I created a fresh project, swipe does work but tapping delete does nothing.  I tried putting the code in `viewDidAppear`, `viewWillAppear`, `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.  Removing the code makes it work, or by changing the last line to `self.view.addSubview(tableView)` similar to the next answer

Comment: @JohnDoe [This](https://gist.github.com/bgayman/18471d780a8a47916e8e312d47c5ad7f) is the code I used to test that. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I commented out the references to  `PlaygroundSupport` and it does indeed work

Comment: I know now why the code above does not work for me.  You need to change   the hard-coded first line to `let containerView:UIView = UIView(frame: tableView.frame)`

Comment: I had it that way before when you first mentioned it didn't work, but that won't make sense for all case, so I changed it to something arbitrary. I thought it was implied to use something sensible. Like the container view can have some origin, but if you are adding the table view as a subview of the container view, then the table view's origin should be `CGPoint.zero` and the table view and container view's size should be equal. I'll make that more clear in my answer. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Nice solution, neat way to get a border on a table.

Answer (score 5):

The RDC's answer is good, but for me the result didnt resolve my case, follow is my fix :

```
//for table view border
tableView.layer.borderColor = UIColor .grayColor().CGColor
tableView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0

//for shadow
let containerView:UIView = UIView(frame:self.tableView.frame)
//dont use clear color,fit blue color
containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
//shadow view also need cornerRadius
containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
containerView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
containerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-10, 10); //Left-Bottom shadow
//containerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(10, 10); //Right-Bottom shadow
containerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
containerView.layer.shadowRadius = 2

//for rounded corners
tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
tableView.layer.masksToBounds = true
self.view.addSubview(containerView)
self.view.addSubview(tableView)
```

Comment: I appreciate your efforts :)

Comment: This worked for me when the above answer didn't. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

i tried above solution but in my application tableview didSelectRowAt was not working.

use this Extension for UITabeleView
for corner 
for shadow

//if u want shadow for all side use (shadowOffset = .zero)

```
extension UITableView {
    func addCorner(){
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }

    func addShadow(){
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        self.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
    }
}
```

How to use::

```
   self.tableView.addCorner()
   self.tableView.addShadow()
```

Comment: this way tableview cell goes over the navigation bar when swiped. how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @beyowulf

I have upgraded for me with **Swift 2.2**, to

- set **Border**,
- **Rounded corner** and
- **Drop shadow** to the table view

  ```
  //for table view border
  tableView.layer.borderColor = UIColor .grayColor().CGColor
  tableView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0

  //for shadow
  let containerView:UIView = UIView(frame:self.tableView.frame)
  containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
  containerView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
  containerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-10, 10); //Left-Bottom shadow
  //containerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(10, 10); //Right-Bottom shadow
  containerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
  containerView.layer.shadowRadius = 2

  //for rounded corners
  tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
  tableView.layer.masksToBounds = true
  self.view.addSubview(containerView)
  containerView.addSubview(tableView)
  ```

result looks like

[image]

Comment: the code works but y position strange, let's try modify clearColor() line to containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor(); add containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 10; modify containerView.addSubview(tableView)
 to [code]self.view.addSubview(tableView);[/code]