# Tableview rounded corner not showing up in bottom

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using corner radius to set rounded border of UITableView, Following is my code

```
self.tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
self.tableView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

But its showing like this without rounded corner in bottom :(

[image]

Comment: check your constraint i think is going to the out of view check that first bottom constraint

Comment: Set `clipsToBounds` to true. As Divyesh said the tableview frame could be out of bounds.

Comment: @DivyeshGondaliya clipsToBounds = true did not help

Comment: first check your tableview height @Abhishek

Comment: @DivyeshGondaliya seems like thats the issue, I have given static height of 120 but two cells are less than 120

Comment: set clipsToBounds for Cell also

Comment: @Abhishek please visit below link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33794065/1746086

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was doing rounding corners in awakeFromNib(), instead you MUST do it in layoutSubviews() and it works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

If your table height is proper then, your second cell inner view's height is greater that its height.

Try removing your inner view from cell or if there is no inner view then check your tableview height.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Manish, seems like height is the issue, I have given static height of 120 but two cells are less than 120

Comment: What is tableview height?

Comment: 120, while two cells are 44 each

Answer (score 0):

I set up a quick demo project with a sample viewcontroller containing the following code:

```
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView! {
    didSet {
        tableView.rowHeight = 44
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { return 2 }
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
}
```

In storyboard the viewcontroller looks like this:

[image: storyboard]

As you can see the tableview has a fixed height of 128pt. Although the tableview contains only two rows with a height of 44pt each (88pt in total) the tableview's corners look fine. So there has to be some other issue in your code.

[image: simulator]