# tableview xcode swift with rounded borders

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

I created a table view with a custom prototype cell but I need to shape the borders, this is the image I have now

[the one i get when i run the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6VAx.png)

[this is the prototype cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXnQH.png)

please note that I created a new class for the tableviewcell where I added a textfield to be changed from a list

I want to set the corners radius
i tried to add this code,

```
layer.cornerRadius = 10
```

and

```
layer.masksToBounds = true
```

in the user defined runtime attributes like I did before for a button but it doesn't work

**Here is the code:**

```
import UIKit

class ListOffersViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    let profil = ["Eric","Eric","Eric","Eric","Eric","Eric"]

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return profil.count
    }


    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ListOffersViewControllerTableViewCell

        cell.profilName.text = profil[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Which view you want setup rounded corners?
UITavleViewCell?

Comment: i want to make every cell with rounded corners and shadow,i've seen some other posts but there is some code that I need to add and i don't know where to add it exactly

Comment: @LLIAJLbHOu I've seen this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33793211/tableview-rounded-corners-and-shadow but i don't know where to add this code exactly

Comment: Look at my answer. I move it to willDisplay function.

Answer (score 1):

Be attentive when you work with UITableViewCell. UI features you mind make with contentView.
Here is example.

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    let identifier = "roundedCell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath)"

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cell.backgroundColor = .red
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .blue
        cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    }

}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: when i added the new function it worked with blue background color,i want to set it to white,so when i did nothing happened,I think it's because there is no shadow,right?

Comment: Setup

cell.backgroundColor = .clear

And

cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .white

Comment: Of course, you can setup shadow. But do it with cell.contentView.layer

Comment: can you explain more how can i add the shadow

Comment: i added this code but i can only see the shadow for inside content like the buttons,the texfields.. not the borders of the cell
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cell.contentView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        cell.contentView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2.0, height: 2.0)
        cell.contentView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        cell.contentView.layer.shadowRadius = 2

Comment: I think this may helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754392/uiview-with-rounded-corners-and-drop-shadow

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a UIView on the cell and set the constraints so that it is the same size as the cell. Put all your design objects inside that view. Connect that view to your cell file, then add the corner radius to that view. Make sure you set the cell view background to transparent, and add colour to the new UIView.

Comment: is there any method just by adding a code,and what is the difference btw the one i use now and the one you suggested?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Are you talking about adding the UIView programmatically?

Comment: i followed this tutorial 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uBesaTUJZi0
i don't know how the UIView work because I'm beginner
in the video they added a prototype cell and they customize it by adding some textfields and image..