# How to style tableview sections with shadow, padding and rounded corners?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to rebuild the app from the screenshot in Swift. I want to use a tableview with different tableview sections. How do I style the tableview SECTIONS with padding (left right and top), rounded corners and shadow?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TableView rounded corners and shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33793211/tableview-rounded-corners-and-shadow)

Comment: No, because I want to add the shadow, rounded corners and padding to the sections

Comment: True, but you could use a similar technique for your sections. Also, a quick search on SO shows there are several other questions about this. I also recommend you read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be achieved by simply adding uitableview as a cell of uitableview and add the shadow and border to each cell.